# Excel multiple sumifs / lookup formula

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a table of Data as follows

```
05/02/16    WIL003003   159.46
05/04/16    ALK001003   940.00
31/03/16    UNI003003   26,041.16
31/03/16    COL001003   21,815.66
11/04/16    UNI003003   28,790.24
11/04/16    COL001003   6,818.00
11/04/16    UNI003003   21,972.24
27/04/16    CLE002003   380.00
29/04/16    LEV001003   1,249.32
06/01/16    LEV001003   1,249.32
05/05/16    PEA001003   1,338.40
05/01/16    PEA001003   1,165.70
```

on a summary sheet, I have columns by month and rows by project number, as follows

```
Reference       JAN'16  FEB'16  MAR'16  APR'16
UNI003003                   
COL001003                   
CLE002003                   
LEV001003                   
PEA001003                   
ALK001003
```

What formula is needed to look up the month and project ref, from the data above and add to the relevant months and projects in the summary?

Comment: Dibs on saying look up pivot table!

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming:

- Second table is in the range A1:E7
- First table is in the range G1:I12
- The dates are in an excel date serial formatted to display as the dates shown for both column data and header data
- That you are trying to sum the appropriate values from the third column in your first table

Place the following formula in B2 and copy down and right as required:

```
=sumproduct((month(B$1)=Month($G$1:$G$12))*($A2=$H$1:$H$12)*I1:I12)
```